# How to update several registers with different values in a single query using prisma

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, prisma

I am in a situation where I need to update multiple records at a time using prisma, however I have run into a problem using `updateMany`, it can only set a value for the field in all records that fit the condition.

I need something like `UPDATE table SET field = "new value" WHERE id = 1,  UPDATE table SET field = "new value 2" WHERE id = 2`.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this dynamic update using prisma in one query? or how to make a dynamic raw query with js itself?

I tried to do something like the code below, but it was unsuccessful

```
    async updateProductsQuantity(
        data: IUpdateProductsQuantityDTO
    ): Promise<void> {
        await prisma.product.updateMany({
            where: {
                id: {
                    in: data.ids
                }
            },
            data: {
                currentQuantity: data.quantities
            }
        });
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't native support for passing different where clauses in updateMany, there is a Feature request for it here: [#6862](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6862)

For now, you can use [transactions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#transaction-api) to make sure both the update queries are executed. Though it will be two different queries, but you would be able to ensure that both of them either pass or both fail.